# General Steps to immigrate to Canada as a Family

Tags: immigration, canada

I have been looking into how to migrate to Canada as a family

- Me: 47 years - developer with 22 years of experience (in my country)
- Wife: 38 years - graduates by Nov-2023 in Business Management
- Kid: 8 years (school)

Other details about me:

- I have presented the IELTS General with a overall score 7.0
- I have never worked or lived in Canada
- I have selected the range of $16,570 - $20,222 for 3 family members

Yesterday I followed the official wizard/form that it helps me to determine if I can use Express Entry with the above details and it told me that I was not able to use it (even when selecting that I had a job offer). The wizard I used is this one: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/come-canada-tool-immigration-express-entry.html

Someone has told us that a way to migrate is that my wife studies a postgraduate in Canada and that meanwhile I can work there, but **what are the general steps to achieve that** besides choosing a university program, getting the money and submitting the papers to the college?

For example does she need to get the visa first and then I submit my application to go there or is this an application that the both of us have to do together in single process?

Is that the better option for us? Is the above wizard reliable for this case?

We area planning on contacting an immigration agent for this case but I still want to understand our options.

The **IELTS scores requiered by Canada** is mention here
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/language-requirements/language-testing.html

The **amount of money you need to migrate** (not salary) is on this table
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html

Comment: They don't ask for an overall, average score of 7.0 but each of the 4 categories must be 7.0 or higher. Did you have that? Something else which may have caught you is that they now expect 20371 funds to bring to Canada for subsistence if there are 3 family members.

Comment: @PeterGreen they are not asking about salary, they have a table https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html - Also I never though that asking for guidance would become a matter of me being a "decent software developer" or not

Comment: @mkennedy - as far as I know they ask for a CLB of level 7 or higher they have this table to convert IELTS scores to CLB levels- https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/language-requirements/language-testing.html - I'm a C1 (native)

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause of Illegibility

One obvious reason is that the fund you planned to bring was not enough, 17K only enough for family with 2 members. You need to bring [at least 21'055 for 3 people](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html#table) so you should choose 21,055 - 25,563 range (the ranges changed a bit since your posting).

Another possible reason is your IELTS score, as you did not mentioned all 4 scores, any of those below 6 ([equivalent to level 7 CLB](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/standard-requirements/language-requirements/test-equivalency-charts.html)) [will disqualify you](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/federal-skilled-workers/six-selection-factors-federal-skilled-workers.html#language), regardless of overall score.

In general, for Express Entry - Federal Skilled Worker - you should read thoroughly the [Six selection factor](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/federal-skilled-workers/six-selection-factors-federal-skilled-workers.html) and also [some additional requirements](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/federal-skilled-workers.html#proof).

#### Advance Education to Immigrate

Indeed the most likely to succeed procedure is to go to post-secondary in Canada and get a degree (keep in mind that long distance education does not work). However, in general the school and degree itself does not directly allows immigration (the exceptions are [Master](https://www.ontario.ca/page/oinp-masters-graduate-stream) and [PhD](https://www.ontario.ca/page/oinp-phd-graduate-stream) Ontario PNP, but there are limited seat chosen by a scoring mechanism). Instead, the degree make it much easier for the student to get work in Canada (there are [post-graduation work permit](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/study-permits/post-graduation-work-permit-program.html) and the degree can also help), and while the student still studying it will also [allows the spouse to work](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/work/help-your-spouse-common-law-partner-work-canada.html). Assuming the work is excellent, the employer will more likely willing to go through LMIA certification process to sponsor either the graduate or the spouse for work permit and PR or in most provinces (not Ontario nor Quebec) allow them to get provincial nomination in PNP to get further work permit and PR.